# Xcodebuild fail flutter

Tags: flutter, xcodebuild

I am new to flutter and Xcode, I got a new MacBook pro m1 max and I have a problem with my Xcode build when I try to launch my flutter application, flutter doctor gives me this error:

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm, locale en-FR)
    • Flutter version 3.3.8 on channel stable at /Users/rixez/Developers/medissimo/mobil/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 52b3dc25f6 (8 days ago), 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0
    ✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
      See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information
```

and when I try to launch the application here is the message.

```
2022-11-17 10:24:39.622 xcodebuild[5938:33408] apply_selection_policy_once: avoid use of removable GPUs (via com.apple.dt.xcodebuild:GPUSelectionPolicy->avoidRemovable)
```

Do you have an idea to get rid of this problem?

I tried to change the GPUSelectionPolicy->avoidRemovable but it didn't change anything

Comment: Have you checked the link that's displayed on your console? I.e. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207

Comment: Yes but without success

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing Rosetta as described here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Developing-with-Flutter-on-Apple-Silicon

Comment: @Rãzvan Puiu I am on macos

Comment: I have edited the answer. Can you please try this?

Comment: I tried and it's ok ! thank you

Comment: Happy I could help! Please consider marking the answer as correct. Maybe it will help other people as well.